# Vim: copy, then paste more than once

Tags: vim

I use the highlight mode in vim to copy a few characters.  I then want to paste more than once.  My current technique does not work well.

Sample text: `Linux Solaris Irix HP-UX`

Suppose I want to copy the word `Linux`, then paste over `Solaris` and `Irix`.

1. Place cursor at `L` in `Linux`
2. Command `v` (for visual hilite), then `e` (for end-of-word), then `y` (for yank/copy)
3. Now `Linux` is on my "vim clipboard"
4. Move cursor to `S` in `Solaris` (first instance)
5. Command `v` (for visual hilite), then `e` (for end-of-word), then `p` (for paste)
6. Text is now: `Linux Linux Irix HP-UX`, but now `Solaris` is on my "vim clipboard"
7. Move cursor to `I` in `Irix` (second instance)
8. Command `v` (for visual hilite), then `e` (for end-of-word), then `p` (for paste)
9. Text is now: `Linux Linux Solaris HP-UX` which is not what I expected.

I resort to using highlite/paste with the mouse (via X Terminal).  Surely, I can do this better.  How?

Answer (score 8):

I would do that in this way (really useful for many paste):

1. Go somewhere into the word `Linux`, then <kbd>"ayiw</kbd> to copy the word

   - <kbd>"a</kbd> to select register «a»
   - <kbd>y</kbd> for copying
   - <kbd>i</kbd> to specify we are "in" (the word, the paragraph, ...)
   - <kbd>w</kbd> to choose the word
2. Got to next word <kbd>w</kbd> (or somewhere into the word)
3. Paste on time and save that as macro <kbd>qbdiw"aPq</kbd>

   - <kbd>qb</kbd> to start recording macro in register «b»
   - <kbd>d</kbd> for deleting
   - <kbd>i</kbd> to specify we are "in" (the word, the paragraph, ...)
   - <kbd>w</kbd> to choose the word
   - <kbd>"a</kbd> to select the register «a» (previously saved)
   - <kbd>P</kbd> to paste the word before the cursor
   - <kbd>q</kbd> to stop recording the macro
4. Then to use the macro the first time, go to the next word <kbd>w</kbd> and press <kbd>@b</kbd>
5. Finally, and it is where the advantage of this method can be seen, go the each word you want to replace and press <kbd>@@</kbd>

**Hint:** Replace the <kbd>w</kbd> by <kbd>W</kbd> in <kbd>qbdiw"aPq</kbd> to select word with punctuation, like `HP-UX`

**Issue:** When the word is the last in the line it will delete the space before the word.

Answer (score 2):

I need this so often, I wrote a plugin to simplify and allow maximum speed: [ReplaceWithRegister](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2703).

This plugin offers a two-in-one `gr` command that replaces text covered by a {motion} / text object, entire line(s) or the current selection with the contents of a register; the old text is deleted into the black-hole register, i.e. it's gone. It transparently handles many corner cases and allows for a quick repeat via the standard `.` command. Should you not like it, its page has links to alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily for you and me, this question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7163947/7659430) and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7164121/7659430) on StackOverFlow. You can alter the default behaviour of <kbd>p</kbd> to be more intuitive or handy for some, by adding the following to your `vimrc` file:

```
xnoremap p pgvy
```

Comment: This is very neat!

Answer (score 1):

Use registers and avoid visual mode.

```
Move to 'L' (type 0fL)                  |L|inux Solaris Irix HP-UX
"lye                                    
'Linux' is now in the 'l' register.     
Move to 'S' (type fS)                   Linux |S|olaris Irix HP-UX
"sde"lP                                 Linux Linu|x| Irix HP-UX
'Solaris' is now in the 's' register.   
Move to 'I' (type fI)                   Linux Linux |I|rix HP-UX
"ide"lP                                 Linux Linux Linu|x| HP-UX
```

You could also just delete 'Solaris ' and 'Irix ' and paste 'Linux ' twice in their place.

```
0fLw2dwbyf<space>w2P
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider `"0p` when pasting in visual mode.

Ref `:help v_p`

```
Move to L in Linux
ye     # Yank to end of word.
w      # Move to next word.
<C>ve  # Highlight Solaris.
"0p    # Paste Linux, Solaris ends up in unnamed register and Linux in 0
w      # Move to next word.
<C>ve  # Mark next word. (Or anywhere else)
"0p    # Paste Linux.
```

Or in this exact example one could also:

Positioned on `L` in Linux

```
yww<C>v2f 2p
# Or
yww<C>v2el2p
yw           # Yank Linux 
w            # Move to S in Solaris
<C>v2el      # Enter visual mode, highlight two * end, and l to consume space.
2p           # Paste Linux twice.

'<C>v2f '    # Alternative to <C>v2el
```

Comment: Or `"_deP` -- `"_` is the "black hole register", and acts like /dev/null.